# Is there a way to display a custom post type menu item as "users" submenu?

Tags: custom-post-types, admin-menu

"client" is a custom post type because I have to add several metaboxes.
For a better ergonomy on admin side, I would like to add my custom post type "client" as "users" submenu.

I understand to display a custom post type, normally urls are :

1. https://my-site.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=client
2. https://my-site.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=client

When I add "client" inside users menu, I got this url :

https://my-site.com/wp-admin/users.php?page=client

So, that does not work.

How can I get the client edition with list/post-new/edit-new based on the last url ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1  (not a good idea):

```
 add_users_page(
   _x( $this->page_title, "page_title", $this->text_domain ),
   _x( $this->menu_title, "menu_title", $this->text_domain ),
   $this->capability,
   "edit.php?post_type=my-post-type"
);
```

*Notice : This code is used in a class.*

> When you are on the page, it can have some bugs with the menu, it´s a good idea for specific page

Solution 2 :

```
register_post_type(
  'my-post-type',
  array( 
      'show_in_menu' => "users.php"
  )
);
```